# storing instances in variables in python

Tags: python, input, pyqt4, instances

In my Pyqt4 program I want to change the shortcut for some buttons. As I have quite a lot I thought of accessing a button through user input. I copied the relevant code snippets.

```
    self.btn3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)

    b, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Keyboard Mapping', 
            "Enter button number: ")
```

so the user would, say, input "btn3", and then in another input dialog he'd specify the new shortcut. Finally, I want to change the button shortcut like this:

```
    self.b.setShortcut(newkey)
```

I get an error that my QMainWindow Class has no attribute "b".

Is there no way of storing an instance in a variable? Or maybe reading the variable or something? I'd be glad if you can help me...

Comment: You never defined `self.b`, why do you think it exists? Did you meant `self.btn3`?

Comment: no "b" is the "btn3" from the user input, so I want to store the "btn3" string in the "b" variable and then use it as the instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that python doesn't take the value from `b` for the lookup when you do `self.b.setShortcut(newkey)`, rather, it just looks for the name `b`.

You can do what you want using [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(self, b).setShortcut(newkey)
```

However, this is bad style and will generally be unsafe and cause problems. Instead, make a data structure that suits your need - here it would make sense to create a dictionary, for example:

```
self.widgets = {"btn3": QtGui.QPushButton(self)}
...
self.widgets[b].setShortcut(newkey)
```